# Using tapply on Function that has multiple outputs

Tags: r, tapply

I have some data where we apply multiple tests (called parameters) to different "die", and each "die" can either pass or fail a given test.

Here is a small portion of a dataframe named alldie

```
    die                        parameter firstfailure
1     1 Resistance_Test DevID (Ohms) 428        FALSE
2     1         Diode_Test SUBLo (V) 353        FALSE
3     1        Gate_Test V1_WELL (V) 361        FALSE
4     1        Gate_Test V2_WELL (V) 360        FALSE
5     1        Gate_Test V3_WELL (V) 361        FALSE
6     1  Class_Test Cluster Class2 (#) 6        FALSE
7     1   Class_Test Column Class1 (#) 2         TRUE
8     1  Class_Test Cluster Class1 (#) 2           NA
```

If I provided the full dataset, you'd see multiple die (numbered 1,2,3,...), many more different parameters, and under firstfailure, you would see FALSE (die passed) or TRUE (die failed) and occasionally NA if the test wasn't performed.

I thought I could compute the number of die going through each test (parameter), the number that passed, and the proportion that passed, by writing a function and then using `tapply`

```
ly <- function(data) {
  ndie <- sum(!is.na(data))
  npass <- ndie - sum(data,na.rm = TRUE)
  yield <- npass / ndie
  c(npass,ndie,yield)
}
```

This does the calculations I want, but produces some difficult to use output

```
tapply(alldie$firstfailure, alldie$parameter, ly)) -> lim_yld
```

then lim_yld looks like (first few rows only, and also `tapply` puts the parameters in alphabetical order)

```
$`Class_Test Cluster Class1 (#) 2`
[1] 76 76  1

$`Class_Test Cluster Class2 (#) 6`
[1] 89 89  1

$`Class_Test Column Class1 (#) 2`
[1] 76.0000000 89.0000000  0.8539326
```

Questions:

1. How can I get the data into a dataframe that is more readable? Something like this:
   `Parameter                      Npass Ndie    Proportion
   Class_Test Cluster Class1 (#) 2   76   76     1.0000000
   Class_Test Cluster Class2 (#) 6   89   89     1.0000000
   Class_Test Column Class1 (#) 2    76   89     0.8539326`
2. How can I sort the parameters in this dataframe in the original order?

Thanks!

Comment: I haven't tried reading in your example data, but maybe `lapply(split(alldie$firstfailure, alldie$parameter), ly)` is more what you're after... or just set `tapply`'s `option simplify=FALSE (which probably does the same thing)

Comment: Thanks, Frank, but this gives the answers as before in about the same relatively unreadable and hard to use result.

Comment: Ok, I see what you're after. One issue is that the column names cannot be automagically generated. You probably want to alter your function to return something with named arguments `c(npass = npass, ...)`. With that, you can `do.call(rbind, lim_yld)`. If you're open to packages, there are easier ways to do this split-apply-combine stuff.

Comment: Okay, that's a big improvement in the appearance of the results! Given that I know the original order of the parameters, can I now sort the table by that order? It seems that the parameter name is a row label and not an actual column in the dataframe, is that right, which seems to imply that I can't sort the parameter names?

Comment: `res[ order(alldie$parameter), ]` is what you're after, I think.

Comment: `res` is not recognized by my installation of R. Is it a part of a particular package?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112535/discussion-between-frank-and-dj-paige).

Answer (score 1):

How about this a solution.  Take the result of the tapply and convert to a dataframe.  The add the column headings and parameter names:

```
df<-as.data.frame(matrix(unlist(lim_yld), ncol=3, byrow=TRUE))
names(df)<-c("npass","ndie","yield")
df<-cbind(parameter=names(lim_yld), df)
```

As the comments mention above not very generic with respect to the column names, but it does align with your function return.  It appears the tapply is returning the list is reverse but just in case this should work:

```
df<-df[order(df$parameter, alldie$parameter ),]
```